# Using VBA to save excel file and hyperlink the saved file

Tags: excel, vba

Just wanted to ask is it possible to save a file in excel using VBA then generate a hyperlink of that file path to be pasted on a different worksheet?

For example, I have a workbook that have two worksheets, Form and Logs. In the Form worksheet, there is a cell that contain a document number. When I run my VBA code, it will copy the document number to the Logs worksheet.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Dim copySheet As Worksheet
 Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

 Set copySheet = Worksheets("Form")
 Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Logs")

 copySheet.Range("I3").Copy
 pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
 copySheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
 Filename:="C:\Users\username\Documents\Saved PDF.pdf"

End sub
```

It will also export the Form worksheet as a pdf file. However, I want a hyperlink of that saved pdf to be placed into the Logs worksheet. Let's say the Doc Number is in Column A, I want the hyperlink to be in column B in the same row as the Doc Number.

Comment: see this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.hyperlinks.add)

Comment: Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
Sub log()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim wb As Workbook, srcSh As Worksheet, dstSh As Worksheet
    Dim src As Range, dst As Range, pth$, docNm$

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set srcSh = wb.Worksheets("Form")
    Set src = srcSh.[I3]
    Set dstSh = wb.Worksheets("Logs")
    Set dst = dstSh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 2)

    docNm = "Log" & " - " & src
    pth = Environ("userprofile") & "\Documents\" & docNm & ".pdf"

    srcSh.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=pth

    dst(1) = src: dstSh.Hyperlinks.Add dst(2), pth, , "Open PDF", "Log"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, the debug says error 424, object required? Does it have to do with dst(1) or (2)?

Comment: @HMProduction a sheet reference was missing before `Hyperlinks.Add` ..hopefully it works now